# Textblock opening viewbox and not navigating

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0, windows-phone-8

i am having a problem with my textblock navigating to a new page! , well the navigation is not the problem!, i have a viewbox that has storyboards connected with it, so when i click on it, the viewbox expands or collapse, but next to this viewbox i have a textblock that has a colour on it, when i click on that coloured textbox, it should navigate to another screen , but what it does is, it first expands the viewbox then in navigates!, any ideas?

[image: without being clicked]
after clicked it opens up , and then navigates,want this to not expand when clicked on the green block

[image: After clicked, it expands, then navigates]

this is coding for viewbox and the textblock_tap event:

```
 private void viewboxHeader_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        vb = (Viewbox)sender;
        Storyboard sbExpand = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard sbCollapse = new Storyboard();
        sbExpand = (Storyboard)vb.TryFindResource("Expand");
        sbCollapse = (Storyboard)vb.TryFindResource("Collapse");

        string Status = vb.Tag.ToString();

        if (Status == "1")
        {
            descend = false;
            sbCollapse.Begin();
            vb.Tag = 0;
        }
        if (Status == "0")
        {
            descend = true;
            sbExpand.Begin();
            vb.Tag = 1;
        }
    }

    private void TextBlock_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/UI/frmWFDocumentDetail.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Thanks in advance!
i use Visual Studio 2012/silverlight/windows phone 8 app! windows 8 sdk

Answer (score 1):

Just mark the event as handled to prevent it from propagating to the parent control:

```
private void TextBlock_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/UI/frmWFDocumentDetail.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply, that did stop the animation, but now it looks like after i click the page kind of reloads then navigates to new page? :P